# "mouse:over" not firing and "mouse:down" returning undefined target using fabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

Here is my issue; I am trying to display "markers" and on **mouse over/out/click** give some actions.

The problem is that no event gets fired on **over** at all and when on **click (down)** in the console I get some feedback, but not of the element per say (target == undefined).

My different shapes are groups in a group called "marker".
And I group everything with the following:

```
marker.add(plateShape, plateLabel, line, indicator);
```

When using

```
marker.addWithUpdate(plateShape, plateLabel, line, indicator);
```

I get some feedback (over being finicky at best) but the layout get completely messed up.

You can comment/uncomment Line 86 to check the behaviour in the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/u7x7az1j/5/

Thank you for your help!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your use of `add`.

Replace `add` with `addWithUpdate` and be aware that `addWithUpdate` takes one parameter at time.

```
marker.addWithUpdate(plateShape);
marker.addWithUpdate(plateLabel);
marker.addWithUpdate(line);
marker.addWithUpdate(indicator);
```

i tried on your fiddle and it works.
Consider replacing rect + triangle + line with a simple parametric `fabric.Path` you can easily build.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It did the trick indeed.
Total beginner with the library and the help is definitely welcome.

Have a great day!

Comment: I read again your question but i cannot see you asking about targeting single pieces of the marker. Anyway this is not supported at the moment by the library but it is a work in progress.

Comment: Ok, got it.

But when I move the objects, I lose then the mouse:over.
How come the coordinates are not in synch? It's still getting the mouse events in the latest position but don't move over to the new one.

https://jsfiddle.net/u7x7az1j/8/

Comment: because you are animating plate width and some left properties, so the group bounding box does not fit anymore the reality. do some debugging leaving the controls and the borders to true, to see if you can manage to recalculate the bbox accordingly. also you are dealing with groups of groups, so is more complicated.

Comment: I understand that by moving the object and changing the shape the coordinates are different. 

But I would have thought that this would have been automatically re-calculated.

Am I doing it wrong or is there a "fabrics way" to make it work properly?